# How to tell if node has been updated via UI form as oppose to programmatically?

Tags: 7, nodes

I am importing/updating nodes from a web service using node_save.  One feature that I want to achieve is when the imported node is changed locally, it should not receive any further updates from the web service.

So, what I want to achieve is:

- Detect when a node has been updated
- If the update was carried out by a user submitting a form (as oppose to programmatically)
- Then flag that this node should receive no further updates form the web service (I don't need any assistance with this part)

I wanted to use hook_node_update but I'm not sure how to tell whether the update was carried out by a user submitting a form.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an additional field in the content type - for example `update_source` - and set the value programmatically.

If the user is editing the node on `node/[nid]/edit` page, set the value to `UI` and otherwise set it to `programmatic`.

You can do this with simple `hook_form_alter()` and URL checks to make sure the user is on `node/[nid]/edit` page. Something like this would work:

```
if (arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) && arg(2) == 'edit') {
  // Your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm building a content synchronisation module, so there are many different content types that will be imported.  Ideally, I would prefer not to have to add an additional field for each of them.

Comment: Then I suggest custom module which will save the flag value and nid in its own table.